# clean url in core PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've gone through the multiple threads on clean url,but still I get confuse on it.I want to use clean url strategy in core php website.I changed my .htaccess file for multiple urls.but my following code works only for one page(one url)

```
 # Turn on the Rewrite Engine
 RewriteEngine on
 # Rewrite for buyleads.php
 RewriteRule ^buyleads buyleads.php [NC,L]
 ## NC makes the rule non case sensitive
 #L makes the last rule that this specific condition match

 # Rewrite for search.php?u=xxx

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  search.php?cat=$1 [L]



 # Rewrite for search.php?u=xxx&subcat=xxx

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  search.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
 # Rewrite for detail.php?u=xxx

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^detail/([a-z0-9]+)$ /detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Question  1. Above code works only for search.php and if I entered www.sitename.com/detail/29 (detail.php code) it works like www.sitename/29 (search.php) . What mistake I have done in it

Question 2. I also want to know is it really possible to make all urls like this through only .htaccess file? Is there any way to create in core php ?

Question 3. lastly I want to know that how can auto redirect to clean url through .htaccess , like CLick this  after clicking user should go www.sitename.com/34/50.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn more about `.htaccess` and `RewriteCond`. I think you just need to add one more condition in each block about when to skip rewriterule. Currently all requests are satisfied by the first block so `search.php`. Hint: Matching strring with URI, obviously there can be other ways, but thats what I can think of right now.

Comment: can you please explain me more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your questions:

1. Your second rewrite rule does not exclude urls that start with `detail/` so your third rule will never be reached as the second one will search for category `detail` and sub-category `29` (in your specific example). You can exclude `detail/` from your second rule but you can probably also change the order of the 2nd and 2rd rules to make it work.
2. Yes, you can rewrite all urls and have your logic all in php. You can send the original path as the parameter and parse / analyze that in php.
3. You should generate your links correctly to start with. That way you don't have to redirect and you don't have to tell the search engines that a page is permanently moved when you do redirect.

A small example for point 2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Now all urls will be rewritten and in your script you can get the original url / path in `$_GET['url']`

Comment: Thanks for answering , but canyou please explain point 1 and 3 little bit more,also what mistake I have done in it?

Comment: I tried to add this line `code` RewriteRule ^(detail)($|/) - [L] `code` before second rule and change the order,now it is showing objen not found page,

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for all pages using language/content negotiation in the Apache configuration (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) along with rewrite rules. Use of an `.htaccess` file is not required.

In apache2.conf file (or httpd.conf) add the `Multiviews` directive, `MultiviewsMatch` directive, and these **rewrite rules**:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

    <Files "*.php">
        MultiviewsMatch Any
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Then save the file and restart Apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

When you declare further directives in apache2.conf, repeat the `Multiviews` directive for each:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
  Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Make sure you enable/un-comment the **rewrite** and **negotiation** modules in apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule negotiation_module mod_negotiation.so
```